# How to generate Jacoco test report for a .jar file?

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

I'm very new to Gradle.
I have written the test suites. However,

jacoco report doesn't show any classes from .jar file

[image: jacoco report doesn't show any classes from .jar file]

With this setting below, jacoco runs very well with normal java files.

This is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.5"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    compile files('libs/PACV1.jar') //this is where I put the jar file
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    }
}

jacocoTestReport.dependsOn test
```